# Boto3 get_products pricing returning 0.00 USD for some instance types

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'm trying to fetch GPU instance prices for the EU (Ireland) region (eu-west-1).
However, some of the instance types have price 0.00, even though the website (https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/) shows them as available and definitely not 0.00.

I'm using the code below:

```
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='nimbo')
instance_types = list(sorted(ec2_instance_types('eu-west-1')))
# Filter by p and g instance types (gpus)
instance_types = [inst for inst in instance_types if inst[0] in ["p", "g"]]

# Use AWS Pricing API at US-East-1
pricing = session.client('pricing', region_name='us-east-1')


for instance_type in instance_types:
    response = pricing.get_products(
        ServiceCode='AmazonEC2',
        MaxResults=1,
        FormatVersion='aws_v1',
        Filters=[
            { 'Type': 'TERM_MATCH', 'Field': 'instanceType', 'Value': instance_type },
            { 'Type': 'TERM_MATCH', 'Field': 'location', 'Value': 'EU (Ireland)' },
            { 'Type': 'TERM_MATCH', 'Field': 'operatingSystem', 'Value': 'Linux' },
        ]
    )

    inst = json.loads(response["PriceList"][0])
    inst = inst['terms']['OnDemand']
    inst = list(inst.values())[0]
    inst = list(inst["priceDimensions"].values())[0]
    inst = inst['pricePerUnit']
    currency = list(inst.keys())[0]
    price = float(inst[currency])
    print(instance_type+": "+"%0.3f %s"%(price, currency))
```

This returns:

```
g2.2xlarge: 0.907 USD
g2.8xlarge: 0.000 USD
g3.16xlarge: 0.000 USD
g3.4xlarge: 1.331 USD
g3.8xlarge: 2.420 USD
g3s.xlarge: 0.796 USD
g4ad.16xlarge: 0.000 USD
g4ad.4xlarge: 0.000 USD
g4ad.8xlarge: 2.130 USD
g4dn.12xlarge: 4.645 USD
g4dn.16xlarge: 0.000 USD
g4dn.2xlarge: 0.838 USD
g4dn.4xlarge: 1.342 USD
g4dn.8xlarge: 0.000 USD
g4dn.metal: 8.724 USD
g4dn.xlarge: 0.625 USD
p2.16xlarge: 0.000 USD
p2.8xlarge: 7.776 USD
p2.xlarge: 0.000 USD
p3.16xlarge: 0.000 USD
p3.2xlarge: 3.305 USD
p3.8xlarge: 14.082 USD
p3dn.24xlarge: 0.000 USD
p4d.24xlarge: 0.000 USD
```

Any one has any idea what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are *many* dimensions to pricing of an Amazon EC2 instance.

Your code is only looking at the first element returned (`MaxResults=1`), out of a result set of over 100 records.

When I ran your code, it was displaying:

- `$0.907 per Dedicated Unused Reservation Linux with SQL Web g2.2xlarge Instance Hour`
- `$0.00 per Reservation Linux g2.8xlarge Instance Hour`

I presume you want On-Demand pricing without any Reservations in place. In this case, you would need additional filters:

```
        { 'Type': 'TERM_MATCH', 'Field': 'capacitystatus', 'Value': 'Used' },
        { 'Type': 'TERM_MATCH', 'Field': 'preInstalledSw', 'Value': 'NA' },
        { 'Type': 'TERM_MATCH', 'Field': 'tenancy', 'Value': 'shared' },
```

(Thanks to [Use boto3 to get current price for given EC2 instance type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51685222/174777) for this configuration!)

The result is then:

```
g2.2xlarge: 0.702 USD
g2.8xlarge: 2.808 USD
```

I suggest that you remove the `MaxResults` setting so that you can see when more results are returned.

Comment: This is exactly right, thanks a lot. Just as a follow up: will these same settings apply when I want to launch an EC2 instance with Boto3? That is, will be there be a discrepancy between the pricing and the ec2 results?

Comment: In some cases, yes. If you want to launch an Amazon EC2 instance with "Dedicated tenancy", then this must be specified when launching the instance. It will default to non-dedicated. Similarly, when launching the instance, you must specify the AMI. This will determine whether there is an additional charge for pre-installed software (eg SQL Server). However, some of it is externally determined, for example whether the instance is charged as On-Demand or Reserved depends upon what Reserved Instance have been purchased and what other instances are currently running.