# How do I find the Prices for different RDS Instance Classes using the Pricing API in Boto3 AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

So I started by trying to find the service code for RDS instances to use with the pricing API's .get_products() method. But when I used .describe_servies() and went through there list of services, I couldn't find a service for RDS instances. So is there a method through Boto3 to find the on-demand price of each rds instance?

I was trying to replicate something like this, but for rds: [Use boto3 to get current price for given EC2 instance type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51673667/use-boto3-to-get-current-price-for-given-ec2-instance-type)

EDIT:
When I use:

```
>>> import boto3
>>> client = boto3.client('pricing', region_name='us-east-1')
>>> response = client.describe_services()
>>> for x in response['Services']:
...     print(x['ServiceCode'])
```

I get this list that doesn't include rds:

- A4B
- AMAZONROUTE53REGIONALCHINA
- AWSAmplify
- AWSAppRunner
- AWSAppSync
- AWSApplicationMigrationSvc
- AWSBackup
- AWSBudgets
- AWSCertificateManager
- AWSCloudFormation
- AWSCloudMap
- AWSCloudTrail
- AWSCodeArtifact
- AWSCodeCommit
- AWSCodeDeploy
- AWSCodePipeline
- AWSConfig
- AWSCostExplorer
- AWSDataExchange
- AWSDataSync
- AWSDataTransfer
- AWSDatabaseMigrationSvc
- AWSDeepRacer
- AWSDeveloperSupport
- AWSDeviceFarm
- AWSDirectConnect
- AWSDirectoryService
- AWSELB
- AWSElasticDisasterRecovery
- AWSElementalMediaConvert
- AWSElementalMediaLive
- AWSElementalMediaPackage
- AWSElementalMediaStore
- AWSElementalMediaTailor
- AWSEvents
- AWSFMS
- AWSGlobalAccelerator
- AWSGlueElasticViews
- AWSGlue
- AWSGreengrass
- AWSGroundStation
- AWSIoT1Click
- AWSIoTAnalytics
- AWSIoTEvents
- AWSIoTSiteWise
- AWSIoTThingsGraph
- AWSIoT
- AWSLakeFormation
- AWSLambda
- AWSMediaConnect
- AWSMigrationHubRefactorSpaces
- AWSNetworkFirewall
- AWSOutposts
- AWSQueueService
- AWSR53AppRecoveryController
- AWSResilienceHub
- AWSRoboMaker
- AWSSecretsManager
- AWSSecurityHub
- AWSServiceCatalog
- AWSShield
- AWSStorageGatewayDeepArchive
- AWSStorageGateway
- AWSSupportBusiness
- AWSSupportEnterprise
- AWSSystemsManager
- AWSTransfer
- AWSWisdom
- AWSXRay
- AlexaTopSites
- AlexaWebInfoService
- AmazonA2I
- AmazonApiGateway
- AmazonAppStream
- AmazonAthena
- AmazonBraket
- AmazonChimeBusinessCalling
- AmazonChimeCallMeAMCS
- AmazonChimeCallMe
- AmazonChimeDialInAMCS
- AmazonChimeDialin
- AmazonChimeFeatures
- AmazonChimeServices
- AmazonChimeVoiceConnector
- AmazonChime
- AmazonCloudDirectory
- AmazonCloudFront
- AmazonCloudSearch
- AmazonCloudWatch
- AmazonCognitoSync
- AmazonCognito
- AmazonConnect
- AmazonDAX
- AmazonDetective
- AmazonDevOpsGuru
- AmazonDocDB
- AmazonDynamoDB
- AmazonEC2
- AmazonECR
- AmazonECS

Comment: You should include your code.

Comment: RDS pricing appears to be [available programmatically](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/12/announcing-aws-price-list-api-programmatic-access-to-aws-prices/). Unsure how this might be exposed in boto3.

Comment: @jarmod Thank you. I was just frustrated because there is absolutely no information about pulling on-demand pricing for rds instances using boto3 on google.

Comment: There's a [paginator](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/pricing.html#paginators) available for describe_services or, as @asdfg suggests, simply request the specific service with the name "AmazonRDS". One way to confirm this name is to use the awscli: `aws pricing describe-services|grep -i RDS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
response = client.describe_services(
    ServiceCode="AmazonRDS"
)
```

The reason you are not seeing AmazonRDS printed is because the response probably contains `NextToken` and you are ignoring it. Read the documentation of what `NextToken` is and how to use it.

**P.S.: Be polite to people who are trying to help you but has no obligation to do so whatsoever.**

Comment: Thank you, I'll figure out how to use NextToken, and thank you for that reminder. You are right...