# AWS Price list API in Golang

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, go

I'm trying to use the aws price list API to get the price of a particular instance using getProducts, but it's been really frustrating to even get the price from the "response" given by the getProductsOutput. Everything is a awsJSONValue, and when I try to index into the awsJSONValue, I get a bunch of "map[] interface {}" issues that I have to continiously cast and it ends up looking really long and ugly (the command), and definitely not reproducible.
Online, there seems to be no way to get the price from this output due to the "map[] interface{}" issues that is returned in the AWS JsonValue and I can't even index into the particular values.

Does anyone have any success in getting the "price" from the getProducts api call in aws price list using Golang? If so, can anyone please show me because I've been playing around and I feel like it shouldn't be so complicated.
Is there any way I can parse through the aws.JSONValue via like a marshalling function or some sort?
Simply put, I want something like this (but in Golang, not python): [Use boto3 to get current price for given EC2 instance type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51673667/use-boto3-to-get-current-price-for-given-ec2-instance-type)

Thanks!

Comment: What does your current solution look like?

Comment: Where you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to achieve it by creating the models with fields I am interested in

```
func CollectInstanceCost(region string, instanceType string) {
    var pricingData aws_model.PricingDataInstance
    sess, err := awsutil.GetAwsSession()
    pricingClient := pricing.New(sess)
    // Retrieve the pricing information for the specified instance type
    pricingInput := &pricing.GetProductsInput{
        ServiceCode: aws.String("AmazonEC2"),
        Filters: []*pricing.Filter{
            {
                Field: aws.String("instanceType"),
                Type:  aws.String("TERM_MATCH"),
                Value: aws.String(instanceType),
            },
            {
                Field: aws.String("operatingSystem"),
                Type:  aws.String("TERM_MATCH"),
                Value: aws.String("Linux"),
            },
            {
                Field: aws.String("regionCode"),
                Type:  aws.String("TERM_MATCH"),
                Value: aws.String(region),
            },
        },
    }

    pricingResult, err := pricingClient.GetProducts(pricingInput)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    pricingJSON, err := json.Marshal(pricingResult)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err = json.Unmarshal(pricingJSON, &pricingData)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

Now you can access the attributes/values using pricingData.

```
type PricingDataInstance struct {
    FormatVersion string              `json:"FormatVersion"`
    NextToken     string              `json:"NextToken"`
    PriceList     []PriceItemInstance `json:"PriceList"`
}

type PriceItemInstance struct {
    Product         ProductInfoInstance `json:"product"`
    PublicationDate string              `json:"publicationDate"`
    ServiceCode     string              `json:"serviceCode"`
    Terms           TermsInstance       `json:"terms"`
}

type ProductInfoInstance struct {
    Attributes    ProductAttributesInstance `json:"attributes"`
    ProductFamily string                    `json:"productFamily"`
}

type ProductAttributesInstance struct {
    InstanceFamily  string `json:"instanceFamily"`
    InstanceType    string `json:"instanceType"`
    Memory          string `json:"memory"`
    RegionCode      string `json:"regionCode"`
    ServiceCode     string `json:"servicecode"`
    ServiceName     string `json:"servicename"`
    Tenancy         string `json:"tenancy"`
    UsageType       string `json:"usagetype"`
    VCPU            string `json:"vcpu"`
    OperatingSystem string `json:"operatingSystem"`
    ClockSpeed      string `json:"clockSpeed"`
}

type TermsInstance struct {
    OnDemand map[string]OnDemandTermInstance `json:"OnDemand"`
}

type OnDemandTermInstance struct {
    EffectiveDate   string                            `json:"effectiveDate"`
    PriceDimensions map[string]PriceDimensionInstance `json:"priceDimensions"`
}

type PriceDimensionInstance struct {
    PricePerUnit PricePerUnitInstance `json:"pricePerUnit"`
    Unit         string               `json:"unit"`
    Description  string               `json:"description"`
}

type PricePerUnitInstance struct {
    USD string `json:"USD"`
}
```